# react-native-firebase_messaging has not defined a default in project.ext.'react-native'.versions.android.compileSdk

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

I'm using `@react-native-firebase/messaging`. when I tried to run the project in android it's return error

```
:react-native-firebase_messaging has not defined a default in project.ext.'react-native'.versions.android.compileSdk in its build.gradle file.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found a solution to this issue. I'm using   `@react-native-firebase/messaging` with firebase Auth and realtime database. this issue produces because of the version.
So, I've removed all firebase libraries and reinstall it and it's working now

Comment: The actual problem was not keeping the firebase/app and concerned dependency like firebase/messaging or firebase/crashlytics in sync or of same version.

Thus, npm uninstall all the @react-native-firebase/***** libs present in you package.json and then install afresh all of them again. This way the latest version of all will be used and it should work.

Answer (score 3):

I was also getting similar error for crashlytics-

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-firebase_crashlytics'.
> :react-native-firebase_crashlytics has not defined a default in project.ext.'react-native'.versions.android.compileSdk in its build.gradle file.
```

I was using `"@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "8.4.5"`, downgrading it to `"@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "8.2.1"` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

upgrading all the firebase dependencies worked for me

Comment: Can you please tell me how you were able to upgrade all of the dependencies? Did you use a command, or do it one by one?

Answer (score 1):

this works on my project:

I use "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^7.4.2"

I changed the file node_modules/@react-native-firebase/messaging/android/build.gradle

```
    minSdk    : 16,
    targetSdk : 28,
    compileSdk: 28,
    buildTools: "28.0.3"
```

Answer (score 1):

Never downgrade your packages! You should be always up-to-date!

My problem was that I installed a part of @react-native-firebase/{package}s and after a couple of months later I installed another part of that {package}s.
The solution is to install all these (or whose which you need) packages at the same time:

`npm install --save @react-native-firebase/app @react-native-firebase/auth @react-native-firebase/database @react-native-firebase/firestore @react-native-firebase/messaging @react-native-firebase/storage`

Answer (score 0):

This works on my project

I run npx jetify on my project root folder